# Make one of select fields required in a form

Tags: jform, form, fields

I have this form.

```
    <?php
// No direct access to this file
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access');

JHtml::_('behavior.keepalive');
JHtml::_('behavior.formvalidation');
JHtml::_('behavior.tooltip');
?>

<form class="form-validate"
    action="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php'); ?>" method="post"
    id="register" name="register" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
    <fieldset>
            <div><?php echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_FORM_TITLE'); ?> <span style="font-weight: bold;"><?php if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'j') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_JOURNEYS'); elseif (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'w') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_WORKSHOPS'); ?></span></div>
            <hr />
            <div style="font-size: 0.8em;"><?php echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_FORM_DESC'); ?></div>
            <hr />
            <?php echo $this->form->getInput('journey','',$this->journey->id); ?>
        <dl>
            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('name'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('name'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('nclient'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('nclient'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('name_lab'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('name_lab'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('function'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('function'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('service'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('service'); ?></dd>

            <dt><strong>Dados para recibo</strong></br>
            </br></dt>
            <dd></br></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('address'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('address'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('postal_code'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('postal_code') . ' - ' . $this->form->getInput('postal_code_3') . ' ' . $this->form->getInput('postal_code_desc'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('phone'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('phone'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('fax'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('fax'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('email'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('email'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('receipt'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('receipt'); ?></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl id="receiptname-hide">
            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('receiptname'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('receiptname'); ?></dd>
        </dl>
        <dl>
            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('nif'); ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $this->form->getInput('nif'); ?></dd>

            <dt><?php echo $this->form->getLabel('observations'); ?></dt>
            <dd>Coloque aqui o Titular de Conta</br><?php echo $this->form->getInput('observations'); ?></dd>

            <dt><label id="jform_select-lbl" for="jform_select" class=""><?php if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'j') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_JOURNEYS'); elseif (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'w') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_WORKSHOPS'); ?>:</label></dt>
            <dd>
                <fieldset id="jform_select" class="checkbox">
                <?php
                if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'w') {
                    $for = $this->works;
                } else {
                    $for = $this->journeys;
                }
                $xxid = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('wid', 0);
                ?>
                    <?php foreach ($for as $k => $v) { ?>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="jform_select<?php echo $k;?>" name="jform[select][]" value="<?php echo $v->id;?>" <?php if(($xxid == 0 AND $k == 0) OR ($xxid != 0 AND $xxid == $v->id)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/><label style="max-width: 370px;" for="jform_select<?php echo $k;?>"><?php echo $v->name;?> - <?php if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'j') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_JOURNEYS2'); elseif (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'w') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_WORKSHOPS2'); ?></label>
                    <input type="hidden" id="jform_selectname<?php echo $v->id;?>" name="jform[selectname<?php echo $v->id;?>]" value="<?php echo $v->name;?>" />
                    <?php if($v->date_event != '0000-00-00' AND $v->event_canceled != '1') { ?>
                    <label class="inline" for="jform_selectx<?php echo $v->id;?>"><input class="inline" type="radio" id="jform_selectx<?php echo $v->id;?>" name="jform[selectx<?php echo $v->id;?>]" value="Lisboa" checked="checked" />Lisboa</label>
                    <?php } if($v->date_event2 != '0000-00-00' AND $v->event_canceled2 != '1') { ?>
                    <label class="inline" for="jform_selectxx<?php echo $v->id;?>"><input class="inline" type="radio" id="jform_selectxx<?php echo $v->id;?>" name="jform[selectx<?php echo $v->id;?>]" value="Porto" />Porto</label>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <hr />
                    <?php } ?>
                </fieldset>
            </dd>

            <dt></dt>
            <dd></dd>
            <dt></dt>
            <dd></br>
                <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_strbiomerieux" /> <input
                    type="hidden" name="task" value="register.submit" />

            </dd>
            <dt><strong>Pagamentos</strong></dt>
            <dd>Nome do Beneficiário:</dd>
            <dt></dt>
            <dd>
            <span style="display: none;"><button id="frmsubmit" type="submit" class="validate"><?php echo JText::_('JSUBMIT'); ?></button></span>
                <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('frmsubmit').click();" class="button"><?php echo JText::_('JSUBMIT'); ?></button>

                <button type="reset" class="button"><?php echo JText::_('JCANCEL'); ?></button>
                            <?php echo JHtml::_('form.token'); ?>
                </dd>
                <noscript>
                <dt>Aviso:</dt>
                <dd>JavaScript do seu browser está desativado!<br />O site poderá não funcionar corretamente!<br />para conseguir fazer o registo ative o Javascript.</dd>
                </noscript>
        </dl>
        <fieldset>

</form>
<div class="clr"></div>
```

I have this part

```
  <dt><label id="jform_select-lbl" for="jform_select" class=""><?php if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'j') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_JOURNEYS'); elseif (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'w') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_WORKSHOPS'); ?>:</label></dt>
                <dd>
                    <fieldset id="jform_select" class="checkbox">
                    <?php
                    if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'w') {
                        $for = $this->works;
                    } else {
                        $for = $this->journeys;
                    }
                    $xxid = JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('wid', 0);
                    ?>
                        <?php foreach ($for as $k => $v) { ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="jform_select<?php echo $k;?>" name="jform[select][]" value="<?php echo $v->id;?>" <?php if(($xxid == 0 AND $k == 0) OR ($xxid != 0 AND $xxid == $v->id)) echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>/><label style="max-width: 370px;" for="jform_select<?php echo $k;?>"><?php echo $v->name;?> - <?php if (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'j') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_JOURNEYS2'); elseif (JFactory::getApplication()->input->get('journey', '') == 'w') echo JText::_('COM_STRBIOMERIEUX_WORKSHOPS2'); ?></label>
                        <input type="hidden" id="jform_selectname<?php echo $v->id;?>" name="jform[selectname<?php echo $v->id;?>]" value="<?php echo $v->name;?>" />
                        <?php if($v->date_event != '0000-00-00' AND $v->event_canceled != '1') { ?>
                        <label class="inline" for="jform_selectx<?php echo $v->id;?>"><input class="inline" type="radio" id="jform_selectx<?php echo $v->id;?>" name="jform[selectx<?php echo $v->id;?>]" value="Lisboa" checked="checked" />Lisboa</label>
                        <?php } if($v->date_event2 != '0000-00-00' AND $v->event_canceled2 != '1') { ?>
                        <label class="inline" for="jform_selectxx<?php echo $v->id;?>"><input class="inline" type="radio" id="jform_selectxx<?php echo $v->id;?>" name="jform[selectx<?php echo $v->id;?>]" value="Porto" />Porto</label>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <hr />
                        <?php } ?>
                    </fieldset>
                </dd>
```

That gives me this

[image]

I want to make one of the select fields to be required, even if don't exist any of the items (the form doesn't submit)

I can make all the fields required (where Micologia and HIV works, but I select the two square boxes), but I only want one to be select, and not two.

Answer (score 1):

Make the checkbox a radio button instead of checkbox, make the radio button required, and then follow [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279421/can-you-style-an-html-radio-button-to-look-like-a-checkbox/37909047#37909047) to make it look the radio button look like a checkbox.

Comment: I'd agree with the radio button approach.   I suggest not styling a radio button as a checkbox, though - people will expect a radio button to behave in the manner wanted.  Making a radio button act like a checkbox isn't good for usability because the behaviour is then unexpected.